# Magento PWA: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^4.5 || 6.* || 7.*"

Tags: magento2, pwa

I'm trying to get started [with Magento's PWA tutorial](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/pwa-studio-fundamentals/project-setup/)

I've installed yarn via homebrew

```
$ which yarn
/usr/local/bin/yarn
$ yarn --version
1.22.10
```

When I run

```
$ yarn create @magento/pwa
```

The `create` fails with the following error

```
error ember-cli@2.13.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^4.5 || 6.* || 7.*". Got "14.2.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

If I try with Node 12 and Node 10, the similar things happen

```
error ember-cli@2.13.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^4.5 || 6.* || 7.*". Got "12.16.3"
error Found incompatible module.

error ember-cli@2.13.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^4.5 || 6.* || 7.*". Got "10.13.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

I've been able to work around this using `npx`

```
$ npx @magento/create-pwa
```

but I'm curious if anyone know what (if anyting) I'm doing wrong w/r/t yarn.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message indicates you have something like ember cli present. Maybe it's hooked in via some alias or bash profile entry from about 4 years ago?

The error message matches the values from here
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/v2.13.2/package.json#L149